# How to implement a flip over effect using AngularJS animations?

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-animation

What would be the best way to achieve a [flip over effect](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php) using AngularJS animations?

I would like the flip over effect to occur on click. Every time it's clicked, it should flip over to the other side.

Ideally, I guess, I'm looking for a directive implementation that uses Angular animations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The example behind the link shows how to achieve the effect. What exactly do you struggle with?

Comment: I'm looking for an "Angular way" to achieve this using Angular animations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSgvgVat3cXEjLIpD8x6?p=preview) - here is a **seed** of a configurable angular directive that provides 3d flipping functionality. I do not see any *good* reason why to use `ngAnimate` for it.

#### basic usage

```
<flip flip-width="200px" flip-height="100px">
   <flip-panel>
     content-front
   </flip-panel>
   <flip-panel>
     content-back
   </flip-panel>
</flip>
```

#### Comments

1. It appends css-styles on its own, to be fully independent.
2. In a proper, generic `directive` all names should be configurable.
3. `flip-width` and `flip-height` sets style of `flip` and both `flip-panels`.
4. Directive makes some basic check, if both `front` and `back` are set.
5. First `flip-panel` is `front` and the second is `back`.
6. <del>Due to usage of `transclusion` content of the `flip-panel` may be arbitrary html.</del> (you are right Misha no transclusion needed)
7. It only works in `-webkit`. (**update** to make it work in Firefox, just duplicate all pieces with `-webkit` with no prefix - you do not need `-moz`)

### UPDATE

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/JHBnpGwonxqAm9VISRu3?p=preview) - here is an updated and extended version. It shows what I meant by making the directive configurable. In more details:

1. Introduced `flipConfig` via `provider`, that allows to set in `app.config`:

   - default dimensions
   - css class names
   - speed of the transition
   - if the *flip action* is triggered by a click on the panel
2. Introduced `flip-show` attribute that specifies which side to show.
3. Changing `flip-show` we can trigger the *flip action* from outside of the directive.
4. It works in Firefox and [almost:-)] in IE11.

*(btw: it is just a **seed** and it may be improved in a lot of ways. E.g: specifying axis, specifying origin of the transform, specifying radius and margin of the panels, allowing flip on hover, defaults colors, margins and so on)*

Comment: Thanks for that! What would it take to make it work in Firefox?

Comment: BTW, `transclusion: true` shouldn't be there. Everything works fine without it. And, changing it to `transclude: true`, breaks things.

Comment: @Misha in Firefox you do not need any prefixes. You are right about `transclusion`.

Comment: How to do a vertical flip?

Comment: @AnthonyPillos you have to rotate around X-axis: http://plnkr.co/edit/GpuDuroDRF8RBJw6aU6v?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

I had the same usecase just recently for an angular memory game.

My implementation is the same by the idea of the other answers. I also released the flipping code along with a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/zwacky/pen/bnpCh/).

Github: https://github.com/zwacky/angular-flippy

P.s.: Looks i'm late to the party ;)

Comment: but how to trigger flipping by using a button instead of mouseOver ?

Comment: @Tony you would put the flip function in the directive onto your directive $scope and put in your html a ng-click="flip()".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-click` and `ng-class` to add a class when the flip container is clicked.

```
<div class="flip-container" ng-click="flip = !flip" ng-class="{'flip': flip}">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: lightblue;">
      front
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background: lightgreen;">
      back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is essentially the angular way of doing what [Walsh suggested](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) in his article:

> Adding the flip class to the container element will flip the card using JavaScript -- no user hover required. A JavaScript comment like document.querySelector("#myCard").classList.toggle("flip") will do the flip!

The only change to [David Walsh's css](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) was removing the `:hover` selector - the html structure is unchanged.  It works nicely in chrome and firefox.. but the flip isn't as pretty in IE.

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0dn775vpuoOeh2PS1T6k?p=preview

**Update**
I created a simple directive to encapsulate this basic technique.  It allows you to flip over a black card, to reveal a picture on the other side.

```
app.directive("flipReveal", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    scope: {
      url: '=',
      flip: '='
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a link to a new demo: http://plnkr.co/X4pSav

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer** Based on @artur's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139242/1319998 , but hopefully both simplified and made more flexible.

A custom directive is the way to go, one that can be used as:

```
<flip flip-side="{{side}}">
  <flip-front>
    Front side contents
  </flip-front>
  <flip-back>
    Rear contents
  </flip-back>
</flip>
```

I think it should have certain properties:

- Programatically controlled by an attribute. In this case, a string that is equal to 'front' or 'back'

  ```
  <flip flip-side="{{side}}">....</flip>
  ```

  this would allow programmatic access via the surrounding scope.
- Integrated with `ngAnimate`/`$animate`. Specifically, if `ngAnimate` is removed or disabled, the animation should not occur, but the reveal of the other side happen immediately. Using `$animate.addClass`/`$animate.removeClass` would achieve this, adding/removing a `flip-visible` class together with `display:block` and `display:none` styles to make sure the right side is visible/hidden when the animations are disabled.

  ```
  flip > flip-front, flip > flip-back {
    display: none;
  }
  flip > .flip-visible {
    display: block;
  }
  ```
- Controlled by CSS, with defaults. So if you want to change the duration of the flip, it's a CSS, and not a Javascript, addition.

  So it will have a style sheet to add styles required for the various stages of `$animate.addClass` / `$animate.removeClass` CSS animations explained at [Year of Moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) and [$animate docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) . The class will be `flip-visible`, so the extra classes will be `.flip-visible-add`, `.flip-visible-add-active`, `.flip-visible-remove`, and `.flip-visible-remove-active` classes.

  The full set of styles can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/bbYbMhiURnm6FqC9patp?p=preview, but the main construction is of the form:

  ```
  .flip-visible-add {
    // Initial setup: time and initial, pre-animation, transform
  }
  .flip-visible-add.flip-visible-add-active {
    // Target transform
  }
  ```

Putting all this together, the directive is quite short:

```
app.directive("flip", function($animate) {
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var elements = {
        'front': $element.find('flip-front'),
        'back': $element.find('flip-back')
      };
      $attrs.$observe('flipSide', function(visibleSide) {
        visibleSide = visibleSide || 'front';
        var otherSide = visibleSide == 'front' ? 'back' : 'front';
        $animate.removeClass(elements[otherSide], 'flip-visible');
        $animate.addClass(elements[visibleSide], 'flip-visible');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This can all be seen in an example, together with the stylesheets to make it all work, at http://plnkr.co/edit/bbYbMhiURnm6FqC9patp?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I realise there is a benefit to **not** integrating with the `$animate` service, and having a purely class-based solution.

If you use `$animate` with `addClass` and `removeClass`, but interrupt the animation (say, by clicking quickly and repeatedly on the element), the animation will 'jerk' to its end/starting point, and then animate from that position, at least on Chrome. Using a pure CSS solutions avoids this issue, and always animates from the exact current point, giving a smoother effect.

An added benefit is the solution is also simpler, and you don't need a custom directive.

For example, the HTML can be as follows:

```
<flip class="{{side === 'front' ? 'flip-front' : 'flip-back'}}">
  <flip-front>
    Front side contents
  </flip-front>
  <flip-back>
    Rear contents
  </flip-back>
</flip>
```

I use custom elements, but they don't need to have any directives attached: they are just for CSS to hook into:

```
flip > flip-front, flip > flip-back { 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  backface-visibility: hidden; 
  /* Time can be overriden */
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s; 
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

/* Front visible */
flip > flip-front {
  -webkit-transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(0); 
  transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(0);  
}
flip > flip-back {
 -webkit-transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg); 
 transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);   
}

/* Back visible */
flip.flip-back > flip-front {
  -webkit-transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg); 
  transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);  
}
flip.flip-back > flip-back {
 -webkit-transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(0); 
 transform:  perspective(800px) rotateY(0);   
}
```

This can be seen in a demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/A7IeGa1JEsZishmTDTaK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add / remove a class on click.

If you want to hook into the angular animation system then take a look at the [$animate service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/%24animate), in particular `add/remove/setClass()`. The service is usually used in directives. You might want to create a directive that reacts on a click event and triggers the animation. You even get informed when the animation has completed.

Chances are that it's not worth it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to create 3 divs.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

You then position back behind front using z-index, and flip it upside down using rotateX (-180deg or so). Set a transition on wrapper as well.

Then, on click of wrapper, rotateX(+180deg). This will pretty much infinitely flip it over.

** Update: For angular, bind to click and use setClass to toggle between two classes on wrapper, one at rotateX(0deg) , the other at rotateX(180deg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified version of [artur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139242/247243):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/qasakebe/1/edit)

```js
angular.module('FlipDemo', []).directive("flip", function() {  
  return {
    restrict : "A",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var $panels = element.css({ position: 'relative' }).children().addClass("flip-panel");  
      var frontPanel = $panels.eq(0);
      var backPanel = $panels.eq(1);
      
      scope.showFrontPanel = function() {
        frontPanel.removeClass("flip-hide-front-panel");
        backPanel.addClass("flip-hide-back-panel");
      };
      
      scope.showBackPanel = function() {
        backPanel.removeClass("flip-hide-back-panel");
        frontPanel.addClass("flip-hide-front-panel");
      };
            
      scope.showFrontPanel();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.flip-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .4s;
  
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-hide-back-panel {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-hide-front-panel {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="FlipDemo">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 150px">
    <div flip style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      <div style="background-color: green">
        <div>Front</div>
        <button ng-click="showBackPanel()">Show Back</button>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue">
        <div>Back</div>
        <button ng-click="showFrontPanel()">Show Front</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px">
    <div flip style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      <div style="background-color: green">
        <div>Front</div>
        <button ng-click="showBackPanel()">Show Back</button>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue">
        <div>Back</div>
        <button ng-click="showFrontPanel()">Show Front</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Main differences:

- Works in Chrome and Firefox.
- More flexibility with when the flip happens.
- Just one directive rather than two. Less code.
- I took the CSS outside of the directive for clarity sake.